# How to find alternative for INNER JOIN in triggers for this case?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, inner-join, psql

I find difficult to understand why proceeding the trigger with inner join function, cmd causes error, that: ***psql:createTrigger.sql:46: ERROR:  "currentStudentNumber" is not a known variable LINE 8:  SELECT  COUNT(Student_subject.StudentID) INTO currentStudentNumber***

```
       --rule, that lecturer can not have more than 7 students
CREATE FUNCTION lecturersStudentNumber() RETURNS "trigger" AS $$

DECLARE
    maxStudenNumber CONSTANT SMALLINT :=7;
    currentStudentNumber SMALLINT;
BEGIN

    SELECT  COUNT(Student_Subject.StudentID) INTO currentStudentNumber
FROM rora3887.Subject_Lecturer
INNER JOIN rora3887.Lecturer ON Subject_Lecturer.LecturerID=Lecturer.LecturerID
INNER JOIN rora3887.Subject ON Subject_Lecturer.SubjectID=Subject.SubjectID
INNER JOIN rora3887.Student_Subject ON Subject.SubjectID=Student_Subject.SubjectID
GROUP BY Lecturer.LecturerID;

    IF MAX(currentStudentNumber) + 1 > maxStudentNumber
        THEN RAISE EXCEPTION 'Lecturer can not have more than 7 students';
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER lecturersMaxStudentNumber
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON rora3887.Subject_Lecturer
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE lecturersStudentNumber();
```

I have a file createTrigger.sql with such code.
[My database reliation scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuQrv.png)

Comment: You might get an answer if you tagged this question with the dbms you are using (postgresql?)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the keyword `INTO`:

```
SELECT  COUNT(Student_Subject.StudentID) INTO currentStudentNumber
```

Change `INTO --> AS`

The resulting query will be:

```
SELECT COUNT(Student_Subject.StudentID) AS currentStudentNumber
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: This error I wrote before in my question dissapeared. But now, when i create a table, then create trigger and insert data to database, occurs: "psql:inserts.sql:103: ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead." and all Subject_Lecturer table is empty.

Comment: Follow the hint and write PERFORM instead of SELECT.